# Nexus 4 problems when charging

Tags: nexus-4, charging, 4.4-kitkat

My Nexus 4 is not charging when plugged into wall but it charges when connected to PC USB. When plugged into wall nothing happens, the battery icon shows nothing.
This problem appears and disappears randomly. Few weeks ago I had this problem, then it disappeared and now it reappeared again.

I tried to enable and disable MTP and PTP but didn't solve it.
I tried to use the wall charger on other devices and it wors (sometimes work also on this device)
I tried to plug it in different places and it doesn't work.
I tried to move the cable to check if contacts are good and nothing happens.
I tried different USB cables and the behavior is the same.

What can I do?

**EDIT:** The issue is *temporarily* solved. Here's what happened:

- The device was charging only from PC
- I plugged it to PC and the charge was 11%
- I came back after less than 10 minutes: the device was off and pretty hot
- I turned it on and the charge was 1%. The icon said "charging" but it seemed to charge very slowly
- I turned it off.
- I unplugged it.
- I replugged it to PC: it was charging.
- I unplugged it and I plugged it to wall charger. It was charging.
- Initially the battery monitor reported AC, however after some minutes believed that the phone was connected to USB mode.
- The phone charged very slowly.

**OTHER INFOS**:
Today I was run out of battery and I plugged the cable.

- The battery was 18% but in few minutes went down to 4% (I was gaming with a poker game but it went down too fast as it was short circuited)
- The device has shut down automatically
- The device was warm
- After rebooting it I saw the battery charging but a red exclamation mark was blinking
- The red led (which turn on when it's charging) was noisy.
- The system was extremely slow also when I tried to check the battery manager.
- It was not charging. Sometimes a "flash" was on the battery sign but the manager reported "not charging". Another battery manager reported 38mA and then 0 (as if battery was not working).
- I cooled it down with a fan and it seem to start charging but very slowly (from 1% to 4% in 15 minutes)
- I shut it down and after 10 minutes I turned on again and it was 12%. Then it seems to charge properly (from 12% to 14% in a couple of minutes and current was 34mA), but after some seconds current went down to 9mA and then to 0.

[image: battery status]

<sup>Click on picture for larger version</sup>

Soon after this screenshot it seemed to start charging better, current was more than 200mA, but as soon as I took a screenshot it went down to few mA and then 0 again.

Another update:

Today I plugged the cable when battery was 29%. During the day I checked current usage, it was fine with an average of 200mA. When I plugged the cable (either via USB or from charger) the current usage went up to 1A, again with red exclamation mark, warming etc. I don't know what I should do now.

[image]

<sup>Click on picture for larger version</sup>

NOTE: it's not a short circuit in the Nexus pins because if I plug the cable in it but I don't plug the other end, nothing happens.

**UPDATE**: I tried to plug the phone to other USB ports and it works *with higher probability*. Sometimes the problem appears also in the other USB ports, but less frequently. However the charging current is only 200mA, which doesn't seem correct, in my opinion. Sometimes the phone appears to be in discharge while plugged via USB. I download a CPU monitor to check if the dicharge was due to high CPU load and I verified that when I plug USB the CPU load increases near 100%, see image:

[image: CPU load]

<sup>Click on picture for larger version</sup>

From 19:26.03 to 19:28.49 the phone was plugged to the first USB port, then I plugged it to another port (CPU went down to zero) and the I plugged it again into the first port.

The process which consumes high CPU is **system_server**.

Comment: I am getting a similar experience with my Nexus 7 (2012 Wi-Fi only) and I observe it happened exactly after 4.4.2 kitkat update. I plan to downgrade it to 4.3 to check by this weekend. If you can you too can try downgrading it and have a try.

Comment: I also have a similar problem, but I discoverd that my Nexus 4 will gladly accept my Samsung Tab2 charger for some reason. I can charge the Nexus 4 till full, power it off and the next morning it can have gone to Sleep of Death. But when I connect the Nexus 4 to my Samsung Charger, after a couple of minutes it has woken up and is charging as normal, but with an empty battery.

Comment: It seems that there is something that is draining the battery for some reason, even when I have shut down my Nexus 4.
The good thing is that I have always been able to wake it up by the help of my Samsung charger even if it has lost so much power that I've got the red led as the sign of SOD.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things that could be happening here:

1. It could be that the charger is not powerful enough (either something happened to it or it never was). This means that although charge is going into your phone the phone is using it too fast to add any battery life. To see if this is the case try to charge your phone when it is off or in airplane mode.
2. A software issue could be causing the charging circuit to disengage due to excess charge (this is pretty much a guess).
3. The battery level on the phone (or charging symbol) may not be accurate and therefore not give an accurate representation of charging. To test this see if the phone gains actual usable charge when plugged in (leave it overnight starting at close to 0% and if it makes the night your all good).

Hope this helps.

[EDIT]

Looking at your CPU monitor I have a few more suggestions that might help (more in diagnosing than anything).

Attempt to connect your phone via ADB and access your phone via adb shell (there should be some tutorials around the web which I may post later).

Then use the "top" command to view all running processes.

Identify the offending process (it should have a high CPU load and be named system_server)

Get the PID of the process and run the command: "kill PID" with PID being the PID of the process.

See if this fixes the issue.

Let me know what happens or if you run into any issues (I really want to figure this out now).

Comment: 1) The charge icon would be "in charge" but it's not.
2) it's my opinion too.
3) when plugged to PC works correctly.
I temporary solved it, I update my question.

Comment: What should I do in the case of a software issue? (now I'm 0.999 sure that charger and cables are working)

Comment: If software is causing the problem a factory reset will fix it. Just ensure to backup your device before so you don't lose any data. You could also go into recovery mode to see if there are any options that look promising there.

Comment: Found a good one http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCommandLine/article.html

Comment: about killing system_server: I already tried it using a CPU monitor from device but I don't have root access and I cannot kill it. I don't think that I can killing it from ADB without root access. Am I wrong?

Comment: I am not completely sure but its quite possible you could simply use the sudo command on the command line to give yourself root (for that command at least). I'm at school now but I will do some more checking for you later.

Comment: I don't think that it could work, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934551/how-to-get-root-access-in-adb-shell-for-unlocking-pattern

Answer (score 1):

It sounds similar to a problem I had with a Nexus 7 (2012). I could get it charging by connecting it up to charge then rapidly plugging in and unplugging the USB cable from the power brick (not the phone). This usually allowed it to charge although slower than it should. I called Google and they said it needed replacing. In the EU we have directive 1999/44/EC that allows phone replacements for 2 years. A factory reset did not solve the problem. You could try different leads and open the contacts on the phone. An Apple power brick worked best for me.

Unfortunately it appears to be a hardware fault. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you I will try to contact Google if the next OS update won't resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

i edit my post to tell you no it's not english , i agree i was not way clear , but remember im tryin to help here so be polite

well you know the apple charger you need like this one and you use it with a usb cable that you use to to coonect your phone to a pc and it ll work 
the issue is the hole in your phone get bigger than the charger thats why it works only with a usb cable

Comment: @kosaidpo please attempt to use proper grammar when answering a question

Answer (score -1):

I tried to do a factory reset and it worked.