# Samsung S3Mini - Charge/Discharge problems

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

I've got a strange problem on my S3Mini; two weeks ago has started to behave strangely, emitting the sound of charge/discharge while not connected to the AC adapter and setting the battery icon in the status with the "loghtining" as it was connected on charge.
I've cleaned up the mini usb connector, thinking that maybe it was dirty and it was making some strange contacts but it has not solved anithing.
Two days later it has started to not recognise when attached or disconnected to the charger; it recognize the status only if connected or disconnected while rebooting.

The battery is fine; charging up, even if the phone says it is on battery, and then rebooting show then the real value of the battery.

If I reboot with the charger attached the phone charge and then says for the rest of the day "100%, disconnect from the charger" even when I've detatched from the charger; if i reboot with the charger disconnected the percentage of the battery goes down fine and when I attach the charger it doesn't starts to increase and doesn't recognize that it has been set on charge.

I've tested the battery, cleaned up the contacts on the usb mini and on the motherboard everything is fine: my phone isn't rooted. I haven't tryed to restore fattory setting at this time cause I've got of ton of things to save before.
I don't think is an hw fault because at the reboot it would not recognize that the phone is on charge or not in this case.

Anyone of you have got any idea how to solve this?
If you need more informations just let me know,

Thanks.

UPDATE: the phone doesn't recognize when attached to a pc usb port ant the pc doesn't recognize the phone; I eat my words about my hypotesys for an hw fault......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this post 
[Nexus 4 problems when charging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/63469/nexus-4-problems-when-charging?rq=1)
and then  I've broke my mind and opened the phone; I've cleaned up every contact on the usb side and on the motherboard side then reassemblied the phone: now it seems to work again well.
It was indeed an hardware problem but luckily, a simple one.

Answer (score 1):

I've got an s3 mini too. The issue in my case was that the USB port had a slack joint. I sent it to my warranty service and they changed the jack. Now I can charge again. And also attach your     charger because you'll get a new one